# Server side cache in ASP 5 (MVC 6)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching

Without System.Web[.caching] in ASP 5.  Is there a server side cache available?

I could use System.Runtime.Caching, but then I have to do all the heavy lifting myself, and Redis seems like overkill for this app.

Comment: We need more info on the app - and what you are trying to cache.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly: No.

To answer your comment, it's not overkill to in the simplest fashion implement the 'heavy lifting'.